# Meetup city list widget stylize

Tags: css, plugins, widget, meetup

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer for this. I am trying to find a way to stylize the "City List" widget for Meetup.

The first widget on this list is the one I am trying to stylize. (http://www.meetup.com/makermeetup/widgets/)

They do not have a way to customize it, and I have looked in the widget foundry, searched online, and am not able to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to customize the styling, not the content of the widget. You need to access the elements in the iframe and set new css rules. Find more in attached link about how to access the elements within the iframe. [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: Unfortunately, the iframe has a different domain than mine.  I am not able to use that solution.